# Differents explorers arent synchronized

Tags: blockchain, testnet, blockexplorer, dash

I have this testnet address: `yehZoVH57FwDFC7vBRGK5ptuYHG9DfL2cf`

I had used this faucet twice:
http://test.faucet.masternode.io/

When I access this explorer:
https://test.insight.dash.siampm.com/address/yehZoVH57FwDFC7vBRGK5ptuYHG9DfL2cf

My balance here is 77.5262, **but**

When I access this explorer:
https://chain.so/address/DASHTEST/yehZoVH57FwDFC7vBRGK5ptuYHG9DfL2cf

It dont show to me any transactions, and not, mainly, a positive balance such as the first explorer.

Whats happening on here ?

I'm a beginner in this world, so excuse me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explorers are not synced with each other; they display different blocks. It seems like Dash's testnet has been reset multiple times so chain.so is using one version of the testnet which dash.siampm.com is using a different version of the testnet. This means that they are using different blockchains. Thus your transactions will only appear correctly on the one that is using the testnet chain that you are using.

Comment: Thank u, How can I use the testnet of the chain.so ?

Comment: I don't know how you can use the other testnet. I do not use Dash.